# Interfaces and JSON Serialization in .Net

Tags: .net, json, serialization, interface

Is there any JSON library for .Net that allows me to serialize/deserialize classes containing interfaces:

```
 public class MyClass
 {
    public IMyInterface1 Property1 {get;set;}
    public IMyInterface2 Property2 {get;set;}
 }
```

I realize concrete classes will be necessary for deserialization, so I'm assuming they would need to be specified through attributes or as part of the method call.

Edit: One additional requirement - It should not rely on any markers or special properties on the JSON for serialization/deserialization, as sometimes I'll need to read JSON from a 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed do do this using [jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/). You just need to create a mapping class like this one:

```
public class InterfaceImporter<TInterface, TClass> : IImporter where TClass : TInterface
{
    public object Import(ImportContext context, JsonReader reader)
    {
        return(context.Import<TClass>(reader));
    }

    public Type OutputType
    {
        get { return (typeof(TInterface)); }
    }
}
```

Then use this code to map the interfaces to the appropriate classes and deserialize:

```
ImportContext context = new ImportContext();

context.Register(new InterfaceImporter<IMyInterface1, MyClass1>());
context.Register(new InterfaceImporter<IMyInterface2, MyClass2>());

MyClass deserialized = context.Import<MyClass>(JsonText.CreateReader(json));
```

Comment: Something similar can also be done with JSON.Net and the CustomCreationConverter class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class which allows you to work with [known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

Comment: This works with the minor annoyance of adding one "__type" property to each object. A bigger problem is that apparently the deserialization process *depends* on this property, and sometimes I'll need to read JSON from a 3rd party that won't include those attributes. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: @Badaro, on way or another you need to include the type information into the serialize JSON or you won't be able to deserialize it back. The DataContractJsonSerializer uses the `__type` property. If you rely on third party JSON providers that do not include type information in some way you cannot expect to deserialize back into objects containing interfaces. Another popular JSON serialization framework for .NET is Json.NET (http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

Comment: I agree, but carrying this information through the JSON is not the only option. I'm looking for something that allows me to specify it using attributes or allows me to implement a class to perform the interface -> class mapping.